# Using String variables in xml files (android studio)

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

So I try to show the String variable in GUI that I inherit from a parent activity.

This is my xml code

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:id="@+id/Edit_Title_Update"
    android:text="@string/updating_title"/>
```

This is my String definition

```
 <string name="updating_title"> %s </string>
```

This is how I try to put date into the String

```
    String updating_title = getString(R.string.updating_title, show_title);
    Log.e("MyTag","Here2 "+updating_title);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update__diary);
```

In the console I can see the variable is correct

```
01-05 10:19:29.767    2849-2849/com.example.wenhaowu.diaryproject E/MyTag﹕ Here2 Happy
```

But In the emulator the String remains the same

[image]

What is the problem and how can I fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `String updating_title` won't change the *actual* String resource `updating_title` in **strings.xml**.

You would need to set text in EditText in your activity after `setContentView`

Like:

```
EditText e = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.my_edt_text);
e.setText(updating_title);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

nothing is wrong, you just need to find your `EditText` and call `setText` on the instance, to update its content with the new value. After `setContetView`

```
EditText t = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.Edit_Title_Update);
t.setText(updating_title);
```